# Check if the date today is between a range, without using the year

Tags: php, date

I am trying to determine whether or not the current date is situated within a predetermined range of two different dates. What I currently have works fine; although I need it to ignore the year field, and just focus on the day and month, enabling it to work for future years without having to change the dates in the code each time.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today));

$winter = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("21/12/2020"));
$spring = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("20/06/2020"));

if( ($today >= $winter) && ($today <= $spring) ) {
  echo "Generic in timeframe message";
} else {
    echo "Not in timeframe";
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that this  'if' is never going to run... later than winter 2020 && earlier than spring 2020? 
Also testing the code above showed me that $winter and $spring ended being 01-01-1970.. maybe the format is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to always compare dates within the current year, you can just get PHP to tell you the current year, and use that in your winter/spring dates:

```
$yr = date("Y"); //get the current year in yyyy format
$winter = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("21/12/".$yr));
$spring = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("20/06/".$yr));
```